# How to allow non-admin users to enter constants in TYPO3

Tags: typo3, typoscript

In TYPO3 6.x, is there a way to allow non-admin BE Users to enter constants?

Answer (score 2):

You can enable access for the `sys_template` records for non-admins by adding this line into file `typo3conf/extTable.php`, so user will be able to edit records with `WEB > List` module:

```
$GLOBALS['TCA']['sys_template']['ctrl']['adminOnly'] = 0;
```

Of course if you are using `Access Lists` in user's group, you need also check possibilities for viewing/editing `Template` table.

AFAIK, it's not possible to enable `WEB > Template` module for non-admins to make things easier.

**Note:** For more details check [description of **security problem** in the documentation](http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/InsideTypo3Reference/CoreArchitecture/AccessControl/UsersAndGroups/Index.html#a-level-between-admin-users-and-ordinary-users)

Therefore, if it's possible try to change behavior of the content by changes in common page properties or by adding FlexForm configuration to your plugin. Adding the possibility of changing TS templates is the last option that should be considered.